# Writing a recursive function that counts vowels in an array

Tags: c, function, recursion

Here is my progress so far , i've been getting this error "Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" I would really appreciate if someone corrected my code and tell me where my flaws are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int vowels(char *str[],int len)
{
    int i,s=0;

    if (!str || len<1)
        return s;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if (str[i]='a') || (str[i]='e') || (str[i]='i') || (str[i]='o') || (str[i]='u')
        || (str[i]='A') || (str[i]='E') || (str[i]='I') || (str[i]='O') || (str[i]='U'){
            return s++;
        }
    }

    return s;
}


int main (void)
{
    int i,len;
    int pom;
    char *str[10];

    len=strlen(*str);

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
        pom=vowels(str,len);
        printf("%d",pom);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the main flaw is that your function is not recursive, it's iterative.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Any ideas on how it should be?

Comment: `len=strlen(*str);` does not do what you want plus, all the `=` is supposed to be `==` and the `if` should be like this:`if ((*str[i]=='a') || (*str[i]=='e') || (*str[i]=='i') || (*str[i]=='o') || (*str[i]=='u') || (*str[i]=='A') 

|| (*str[i]=='E') || (*str[i]=='I') || (*str[i]=='O') || (*str[i]=='U'))`. You forgot to wrap everything in parenthesis and the `*` is needed as `str[i]` is not a character,which explains the warnings you got.

Comment: `scanf("%s",str[i]);` doesn't allocated to `str[i]`.

Comment: There is an issue every 3 lines of code :-(

Comment: @axiac I know , im sad too. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int vowels(char *str, int count){
    if (!*str)
        return count;

    char ch = tolower(*str);
    int match = ch=='e' || ch=='a' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u';
    return vowels(++str, count + match);
}


int main (void){
    int i, t, pom;
    char str[32];

    scanf("%d", &t);

    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        scanf("%31s",str);
        pom=vowels(str, 0);
        printf("%d\n",pom);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

How to write a recursive function

```
Type function_name ( Parameter declarations ) {
    if( Termination condition of recursion ) {
        return [ End value ]; 
    }
    else {
        Calculation for the next call;
        //Tail recursion call optimization can be expected by the simple call to the required variables to parameters.
        return function_name ( Parameters );
    }
}
```

Comment: `gcc -O2 count_vowels.c -o count_vowels`

Comment: Please add additional information as an edit to your answer rather than a comment.

Comment: My revious comments I have intended that is a tail-recursive call optimization in GCC. Comment is appropriate since optimization is not necessarily to be made in all compilers.

Comment: Assumes, which original did not, that part of string to scan is terminated by a null (which is how it is used in the example).

Comment: @ScottHunter Original uses the `strlen`.

Comment: Everything is meaningless because there is no consistency in the OP's code.

Comment: I think modify it if necessary is not difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it being recursive is important (note change in signature):

```
int vowels(char *str,int len)
{
    if (!str || len<1)
        return 0;
    if ((*str=='a') || (*str=='e') || (*str=='i') || (*str=='o') || (*str=='u') || (*str=='A') || (*str=='E') || (*str=='I') || (*str=='O') || (*str=='U'))
        return 1 + vowels( str+1, len-1 );
    else
        return vowels( str+1, len-1 );
 }
```

Comment: You could shorten the check for whether the first character is a vowel to `if (strchr( "aeiouAEIOU", *str )) ...`.

Comment: Well put Scott , finally understanding this recursive thing. Thanks alot .

Comment: @FrerichRaabe or using a switch in case `string.h` is not allowed, which apparently is a very common homework constrain.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: There are a *lot* of ways to improve the structure, but since OP had issues w/ the recursion itself, figured I'd focus on that.

Comment: @ScottHunter There is some kind of error on the if line , i don't know if its my compiler...keeps giving me errors..

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** Because this answer was accepted but it didn't quite answer the question (it didn't contain the function `vowels()`) I added my recursive version of function `vowels()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/**
 * Return the number of vowels in a string.
 *
 * The characters treated as vowels are:
 *      'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'.
 * The function checks the first character of the input string 
 * then calls itself recursively for the rest of the string.
 *
 * @param  string str    the string to check for vowels
 * @return int           the number of wovels found in the string
 */
int vowels(char *str)
{
    /* The number of vowels found in the string so far */
    int count = 0;

    /* Recursion stop condition: when the string is empty */
    if (! str[0]) {
        /* An empty string does not contain any vowels */
        return count;
    }

    /* Check the first character of the string */
    if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", str[0])) {
        /* Found a vowel, count it */
        count ++;
    }

    /* Recursive call to find the number of vowels after the first character */
    return count + vowels(&str[1]);
}


int main(void)
{
    int i, len;
    int pom;
    char *str[10];

    int count = sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
        /* Hopefully you will not input strings longer than 254 characters */
        str[i] = (char *)malloc(255);

        fgets(str[i], 255, stdin);

        pom = vowels(str[i]);
        printf("%d\n", pom);

        /* Release the memory */
        free(str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the accepted answer is the one that specifically does not address the function identified in the question's title (but rather its driver) -- nice job!

Comment: SO does not allow me to remove the answer because it was accepted. I updated it with my version of function `vowels()`.

Comment: Up vote for being a class act.  ("Nice job" was directed more at the acceptOR than the acceptEE)

Answer (score 1):

`if (str[i]='a')`

should be

`if (str[i]=='a')`

and so on ...

also :

```
return s++;
```

should be

```
s++;
```

Comment: Just noticed another problem, don't return s++, but just increment it. You'll always return 1 in that case, and I'm pretty sure that's not what you want

Comment: Oh yeah haha , so i should just put s++ without the return , thanks man.

Comment: I only pointed out the error I saw in the first place, but Cool Guy and BLUEPIXY are right, you should also allocate memory for your array, and your 'len' is probably not the one you want

Comment: str is not a string, it's an array of string. You'll get an error doing this. You want the length of this array. If this is always 10, use this value. If it can be different but still fixed, store it in a variable. Else, I suggest you have a look at `sizeof()`